# Proof of Open Mapping Theorem via Residues

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis, complex-numbers, residue-calculus

I am working on proving that a non-constant Holomorphic function maps open sets to open sets, using an approach based around the Residue Theorem.

We have taken $f$ to be holomorphic and non-constant on some open region $D$, and $\Gamma$ be a closed path in $D$. Then take $\Sigma = f(\Gamma)$.

I have shown that $$2\pi i \cdot \text{Ind}_{\Sigma}(\omega) = \oint_{\Gamma}\frac{f'(z)}{f(z)-\omega} dz$$

Next step was to consider some disc centred at $z_0$ of radius $R$ contained by $D$, and let $\Gamma_r$ by described by $\gamma(t) = z_0 + re^{2\pi i t}$ for $t \in [0,1]$, and I showed that if we define $F_{\omega} = f(z) - \omega$ for $\omega \notin \Sigma_r$, then $$2\pi i \cdot \text{Ind}_{\Sigma_r}(\omega) = \oint_{\Gamma_r}\frac{F'_{\omega}(z)}{F_{\omega} (z)}dz  = \sum_{a \in Z(F_{\omega})}o(a)$$ where $o(a)$ is the order of the zero $a$ of $F_{\omega}$.

The next stage is to take a $z_1$ in the disk radius $R$ centred at $z_0$ and let $\omega_1 = f(z_1)$. I know that the number of zeros of $F_{\omega_1}$ is finite in the disk, and so $\exists r \in (0, R)$ with $|z_1 - z_0| < r$ such that $\omega_1 \notin \Sigma_r$. I need to show there is some disk in which $\text{Ind}_{\Sigma_r}(\omega) = \text{Ind}_{\Sigma_r}(\omega_1)$ for all $\omega$ in the disk.

My Attempt:

Since $f$ is holomorphic and continuous, then $|z_1 - z_0| < r \implies |f(z_1) - f(z_0)| < \delta$ for some $\delta > 0$. That is, $|\omega_1 - \omega|<\delta$ is a disk of radius $\delta$ for which $\omega_1 \notin \Sigma_r$. Now, since the $\text{Ind}_{\Sigma_r}$ is continuous on $\mathbb{C} \setminus \Sigma_r$, then $$|\omega_1 - \omega| < \delta \implies |\text{Ind}_{\Sigma_r}(\omega_1) -\text{Ind}_{\Sigma_r}(\omega)| < \varepsilon $$

I am not sure how to conclude this - can I conclude from here since $\varepsilon > 0$ is arbitrary, or is it more complicated since it depends on $r, \delta$.

After proving this, I was going to show this implies that all $\omega$ in this disk have a corresponding $z$ in the disk radius $R$ such that $f(z) = \omega$. But again, I am not sure how to proceed with this.

Comment: Your first expression already implies the open mapping theorem.

Comment: I'm intrigued to better understand how that is the case?
Also, I would like to try and work through in the order that the text suggests so regardless, any help with this line of thinking would be great :)